# How to derive CPU usage values over time on Neutrino OS?

Tags: linux, bash, cpu-usage, sh

I have access to the basic shell on `/bin/sh` [QNX Neutrino OS](http://blackberry.qnx.com/en/products/neutrino-rtos/neutrino-rtos) (6.4.1)

I want to plot a graph of CPU usage (increase or decrease) over time. The data values can be percentages. I have tried certain methods to quickly infer current CPU utilization (e.g. as described in [this article here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html)).

How do I gather a collection of these values over time? Are these values stored anywhere? I tried `/proc/stat` with no luck. And I don’t seem to be able to install [`sar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) on this OS.

Comment: I am using QNX Neutrino OS which doesn't have `sar` or a package manager.

Comment: `sar` is really the answer most Linux users will recommend. So I have edited the question for clarity with regards to using `sar` but not being able to use it on QNX Neutrino OS.